# Steam: How to fix LibGL errors on Kali Linux / Debian

Tags: linux, kali-linux, steam

I'm trying to run and install **Steam** on Kali Linux **64bits** and I get libGL errors like :

```
Running Steam on kali kali-rolling 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
libGL error: unable to load driver: r600_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: r600
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

It seem that libGL can't find my drivers (I have **ATI Radeon**). I found multiple solution but no one worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

This solution works fine on **Debian** and **Kali-Linux** in **64bits** and for **ATI/AMD** GPU.

(*From scratch*) Download [steam_latest.deb](http://store.steampowered.com/about/), and you need to install some dependencies for steam and so Steam itself :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install zenity zenity-common libgl1-mesa-dri build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
sudo dpkg -i steam_latest.deb
```

Try here to run `steam` and, if you here, you should get the libGL errors describe above.

According to [this solution](http://elza.me/blog/2016/06/Steam/), you have to delink a lot of library with :

```
find ~/.steam/root/ \( -name "libgcc_s.so*" -o -name "libstdc++.so*" -o -name "libxcb.so*" -o -name "libgpg-error.so*" \) -print -delete
```

and :

```
find ~/.local/share/Steam/ \( -name "libgcc_s.so*" -o -name "libstdc++.so*" -o -name "libxcb.so*" -o -name "libgpg-error.so*" \) -print -delete
```

Run `steam` and have fun !