# How to fix this? (Kali Linux 32-bit in Virtualbox)

Tags: terminal, kali-linux, download, steam

```
root@kali:~# sudo apt-get install -f
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
root@kali:~# sudo apt-get install -f
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem. 
root@kali:~# sudo apt-get install curl
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem. 
root@kali:~# sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up man-db (2.6.2-1) ...
Building database of manual pages ...
df -h
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of steam-launcher:
 steam-launcher depends on libc6 (>= 2.15); however:
  Version of libc6:i386 on system is 2.13-38+deb7u1.

dpkg: error processing steam-launcher (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 steam-launcher
root@kali:~# sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  steam-launcher
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 2,898 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Abort.
root@kali:~# y
bash: y: command not found
root@kali:~# Y
bash: Y: command not found
root@kali:~# 
GDBus.Error:org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._pk_5ftransaction_5ferror.Code4: SimulateInstallFiles not supported by backend
```

bash: cd: Downloads/: No such file or directory
root@kali:~# sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  steam-launcher
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 2,898 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 337668 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing steam-launcher ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
But it's STUCK at Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...

Comment: My Kali Linux can also be used for hacking so I need it.

Comment: As I understand it, Steam needs a newer glibc than the one you have in Kali. I don't really think you can get out of this (updating glibc might break stuff) besides by using another distro.

Comment: By the way, why do you want to run Steam in Kali? Doesn't it go against the purpose of Kali (being a distro of security tools)?

Comment: I want to play two tf2 games at once in Steam by using Virtualbox for tf2 community servers. And this guy told me I should get Kali Linux 32 bit instead of Ubuntu Linux so I took his words. I don't wanna start all over again though by changing it.

Answer (score 5):

I have some pointers for you that should help you out.

- You should first read the [Official Kali Linux Documentation](https://www.kali.org/kali-linux-documentation/) to help you if you run into any issues.
- If not then you should google the specifics of your issue, including the exact error message. Someone else has probably ran into a similar problem as you and has either asked the question and received an answer or created a blog documenting what they did to solve the issue. You should also check out [this site](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) to read up on how to ask better questions.
- Lastly concerning the issue you are experiencing, this statement is directly from the [Kali Linux documentation](https://docs.kali.org/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux) (emphasis mine):

> While Kali Linux is architected to be highly customizable, don’t expect to be able to add random unrelated packages and repositories that are “out of band” of the regular Kali software sources and have it Just Work. In particular, there is absolutely no support whatsoever for the apt-add-repository command, LaunchPad, or PPAs. ***Trying to install Steam on your Kali Linux desktop is an experiment that will not end well.*** Even getting a package as mainstream as NodeJS onto a Kali Linux installation can take a little extra effort and tinkering.

- To put it shortly, you will need to manually install the missing dependencies to complete the installation. I would recommend you use a different Distro if you wish to use Steam on Linux. Kali Linux is a tool for penetration testing, you are not really meant to install just any software on it.
- If you still want to continue, [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/347430/276845) appears related to your issue.

Comment: What do u mean Distro? How am I going to get a different Distro? Do I just download it if so what's the link?

Comment: Linux distribution or distro. Kali is a penetration testing distro,  Ubuntu or Linux Mint are distros that are much easier to use and have well documented processes for installing Steam. Please read the links I provided and look into using something other than Kali Linux if you wish to use Steam.

Comment: Also I can't find software center and when I try to get it in the terminal with a command,it doesn't work because it just says some errors and I tried other ways but I still keep getting errors when I just want to download some .deb files but it show this error GDBus.Error:org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._pk_5ftransaction_5ferror.Code4: SimulateInstallFiles not supported by backend which I can't fix even though I tried other ways. I managed to get Steam installed by terminal commands and editing a steam text file but when I tried to open Steam it wouldn't open!

Comment: Steam is not supported on Kali so I really recommend that you install Ubuntu or Linux Mint or really anything other than Kali Linux. The error you listed is due to you not having all the required dependencies. You will need to install them to actually be able to run Steam. They are listed in your post so you can search for them and install them manually. Please read through everything everyone has linked you.

Comment: So what are the required dependencies to actually be able to run Steam? I was literally spending hours trying to be able to install a .deb file and searched on the web too for related errors but I didn't find much there and I tried the web methods but I don't think they worked or they lead me to other errors.

Comment: According to your post it lists: dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of steam-launcher:
 steam-launcher depends on libc6 (>= 2.15); however:
  Version of libc6:i386 on system is 2.13-38+deb7u1. So you need libc6 version 2.15 or greater. This probably also has a few dependencies to reach that state. You are going to run into what is known as dependency hell if you have to manually install a lot of out-of-band packages. [Here is a guide to installing Steam on Ubuntu](https://itsfoss.com/install-steam-ubuntu-linux/) Consider using Ubuntu and installing Steam from there.

Comment: root@kali:~# apt-get install steam
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package steam is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  steam-launcher

E: Package 'steam' has no installation candidate

Comment: root@kali:~# sudo apt-get install jockey-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package jockey-common is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'jockey-common' has no installation candidate

Comment: If your sources.list looks like [this](https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories) then the [package: steam](http://pkg.kali.org/pkg/steam) should be available. Please consider switching to Ubuntu instead of continuing to use Kali Linux. Please read the article [_Should I Use Kali Linux?_](https://docs.kali.org/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux)

Comment: But how do you download the .deb files without getting this error? GDBus.Error:org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._pk_5ftransaction_5ferror.Code4: SimulateInstallFiles not supported by backend. Also I know you need software center for downloading files I think but I can't install it because it doesn't work.

Comment: You are getting that error because your package, _in this case steam_, is missing certain dependencies. You will have to find those .deb's or libraries and manually install them. But let me reiterate **Kali Linux is not for playing games.** It does not have all of the necessary packages, libraries, and dependencies to get a working installation of Steam without doing everything yourself. Installing packages from source and adding additional or alternate libraries is not hard but adds additional overhead to package management on the system that will not always end well.

Comment: So if I try to install a simple .deb file for e.g. Internet Explorer and I'm pretty sure it's not missing packages or dependencies because it's an official browser not a game app it will install right? I can try that right now for testing to see if some .def files can install.

Comment: I tried these methods but it didn't work https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?2573-deb-packages-won-t-install   it just says root@kali:~# apt-get install steam_latest.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package steam_latest.deb
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'steam_latest.deb'

Comment: What is the results of running this command: `apt-cache search steam_latest.deb`

Comment: There is no results,it doesn't show anything. Also apt-get update shows some errors like not found or failed.

Comment: If you do not get any results than you do not have that package in your repositories. It sounds to me that your Kali Linux install is getting pretty borked through this process. You should backup or copy any data important to you and start with fresh install, verify your sources.list has the correct repositories, and start over. Again to reiterate, this process of installing Steam on Linux going to be 100 times easier on anything other than Kali. Ubuntu is a great alternative. Did you read any of the [links?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/399627/276845)

Comment: Lol as in "borked" u mean "to have totally f*cked something up"? XD searched on google what borked means and I guess you wanted to say it in a nice way hiding the real meaning. Also I remember when the install system finished,I saw a blue screen or then grey screen and I just turned it Off and then back On because it wouldn't show the desktop screen and then the screen didn't show it anymore.